# Variable definition inside switch-case

Tags: objective-c, syntax, switch-statement

```
#pragma mark AlertView delegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
            NSString * URLString =@"http://www.google.com";
            NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: URLString];
            NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [webview loadRequest:request]; // Use of undeclared identifier webview
            [self.view addSubview:webview]; // Use of undeclared identifier webview
            break;
        case 1:
            //if Yes button pressed on logout alert
            [self notificationAction];
            [userdefault removeObjectForKey:@"Login"];
            [userdefault synchronize];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to display a webpage. However in Xcode I get the following error on the 1st line of 1st case:

```
Expected Expression
```

Am I missing a header file that I'm suppose to import or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Show more of your code above this snippet - the shown code is perfectly valid. You probably have a syntax error somewhere above it.

Comment: Good advice: don't name your variables `nsrequest` and `nsurl`, those are easy to confuse with the types. Call them `urlString`, `url` and `request`.

Comment: Good Advice. I changed the name of the variables but the code error is being pointed to webview

Comment: It's also a good idea to keep your variable names *camelCase* with lowercase first letter. (eg. `url`, `urlString` etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining a variable on a first line inside a case, you have to wrap code of that case in `{ }`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSUserDefaults *userdefault=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {
            UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024,768)];
            NSString * URLString =@"http://www.google.com";
            NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString: URLString];
            NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
            [webview loadRequest:request]; // Use of undeclared identifier webview
            [self.view addSubview:webview]; // Use of undeclared identifier webview
            break;
        }
        case 1:
            //if Yes button pressed on logout alert
            [self notificationAction];
            [userdefault removeObjectForKey:@"Login"];
            [userdefault synchronize];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Why? Apparently C has problems with scope when defining a variable inside switch-case. Wrapping the code inside `{ }` creates a new local scope.

Comment: This is half true. You only need the curly braces if the 1st line after a `case X:` line is a variable declaration. If the 1st line isn't a variable declaration then you can have variable declarations on other lines without any curly braces.

Comment: True, updated my answer to include that.

Comment: To complete @rmaddy's half truth - a *switch statement* in C is a *computed goto* where the body of the switch is a single *block* and control is transferred to one of the *labels* within that block. A block is a sequence of *statements* and *declarations*, and any declarations are *scoped* to their containing block. And, finally :-), only *statements* can be labelled in C, not declarations. Placing the statements in `{` & `}` as in the answer forms a *compound statement* / *block* - as a statement it can be labelled, and as a block it limits the scope of the introduced variables. Isn't C fun!